# Deceleration of vessel moving at relativistic speed carrying humans

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics

How to calculate time/distance required for a deceleration of vessel moving at relativistic speed carrying humans? assuming humans can handle a comfortable 3g deceleration, is it reasonable to put on the breaks before mars even jupiter's orbit if to be able to stop by earth? or is it suppose to be further out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed [in various questions already on the site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=relativistic%20rocket), though none of them ask exactly the same as you do. The equations you need are give in [Phil Gibb's article on the relativistic rocket](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html). If you start from rest and accelerate at a constant acceleration $a$ the the velocity and distance travelled are given by:

$$ v = c\,\tanh\frac{a\tau}{c} \tag{1} $$

$$ d = \frac{c^2}{a} \cosh\frac{a\tau}{c} \tag{2} $$

where $\tau$ is the time measured by the occupants of the rocket. NB due to time dilation this is not the same as time measured by the people watching the rocket decelerate. If you're interested the article also gives the equations for $v$ and $d$ in terms of the time for the external observers.

These equations assume you're starting at rest, but you just use them backwards. So if you're starting at some velocity $V$ just use equation (1) to work out the time needed to accelerate from rest to $V$ and this will be the same as the time needed to decelerate from $V$ to rest. Then put this time into equation (2) and it will give you the distance.